# Получить тип SQL запроса

Tags: c#, sql

Допустим имеется sqlcommand и в ней находится какой-то запрос.

Можно ли родными средствами получить тип запроса?

Под типом я подразумеваю: INSERT,DELETE,SELECT,UPDATE ?

Понятное дело, что можно получить ключевое слово с помощью регулярки, но можно ли как-нибудь иначе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готового способа нет. Проверяйте, что `CommandType = Text`, а дальше пробуйте выуживать одно из четырех ключевых слов из `CommandText`. Если запрос несложный, то достаточно будет метода `StartsWith()`.

Answer (score 0):

Если создать класс-наследник от sqlcommand с полем commandType, и в месте присвоения свойства commandtext задавать и commandType. То Вы получите родной способ определения типа запроса.

Предполагаю, что тексты запросов неслучайны, есть контролируемые Вами источники этих текстов.